# MySQL select with Disitinct and Where with is_null?

Tags: mysql

Can someone please explain this MySQL query & what it does?

As I can understand it does the following:

Select `invoices_charge` invoice `id`’s without an entry in the invoice table. Is that correct?

```
SELECT DISTINCT invoice_charges.invoiceid as invoice
FROM    `invoice_charges`
LEFT JOIN `invoice`
ON invoice_charges.invoiceid = invoice.invoiceid
WHERE invoice.invoiceid IS NULL
```

Is there any effect of the keyword DISTINCT in this query? is the following query is an better alternative for this query to achieve the same result ?

```
SELECT invoice_charges.invoiceid as invoice
FROM    `invoice_charges`
WHERE invoice_charges.invoiceid  NOT IN  invoice.invoiceid
GROUP BY invoice_charges.invoiceid
```

Comment: Might try on [Database Stack Exchange](http://dba.stackexchange.com) if nobody gets it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query is returning all `invoiceid`s in `invoice_charges` that have no match in `invoice`.

Presumably, these would be examples of a failed foreign key relationship.

The purpose of `distinct` is to prevent duplicates from being in the result set.  You could have two records in `invoice_charges` with the same `invoiceid`, where the `invoiceid` is not in the `invoice` table.

Comment: doesnt that we can run this with a NOT IN query better and with Group BY ?

Comment: @mahen3d . . . `select distinct` and `group by` essentially do the same thing.  `select distinct` is short-hand for a `group by` statement with all the columns.